# Why the `git commit -am` command is working with untracked file (in the documentation's samples)?

Tags: git, git-commit

Often in the Git documentation I see something like [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project):

```
$ git clone john@githost:simplegit.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/john/simplegit/.git/
...
$ cd simplegit/
$ vim lib/simplegit.rb
$ git commit -am 'removed invalid default value'
[master 738ee87] removed invalid default value
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> **-a
>
>   --all**
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have 
>   been modified and deleted, **but new files you have not told Git 
>   about are not affected**.

Pay attention, the `lib/simplegit.rb` file wasn't tracked when it was created at once. Whay the `-a` option does it tracked? I use *Git for Windows* and this sample doesn't work when I try to do the similar:

```
bushm@DESKTOP-ISD2NUH MINGW64 /d/src/sample
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/src/sample/.git/

bushm@DESKTOP-ISD2NUH MINGW64 /d/src/sample (master)
$ vim ./text.txt

bushm@DESKTOP-ISD2NUH MINGW64 /d/src/sample (master)
$ git commit -am "First commit"
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
        text.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present

bushm@DESKTOP-ISD2NUH MINGW64 /d/src/sample (master)
```

Comment: Why *would* 'text.txt' be added, according to "*new files* you have not [added to] Git [are not staged]"?

Comment: This is my question. I don't understand the documentation's sample. I expect it must be not working.

Comment: The example is bit .. wonky, to say the least, but the main point is the following conflict resolution. The scenario presented was the there was a *clone* and presumably an *existing* file, brought over, was modified (such that *a* change was committed with `-am`). With this reading-between-the-lines it holds that the documentation, and the local behavior, is correct: and the example is 'correct' as well (even though the message for the clone is wrong), for it did *not* say a new file was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: the part of the documentation that made this confusing was [fixed](https://github.com/progit/progit2/pull/414/files) in [PR #414](https://github.com/progit/progit2/pull/414) by Matthieu Moy

---

This is probably just a mistake in the example.

Firstly, you are right. `-a` only adds modified and deleted files.

Secondly, when you clone a repo, git doesn't say

> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/john/simplegit/.git/

instead it says

> Cloning into 'simplegit'...
>   remote: Counting objects

and some other lines.

Thirdly, in the example

```
# John's Machine
$ git clone john@githost:simplegit.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/john/simplegit/.git/
...
$ cd simplegit/
$ vim lib/simplegit.rb
$ git commit -am 'removed invalid default value'
[master 738ee87] removed invalid default value
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

you can see the commit message is `'removed invalid default value'`, which implies that it is modifying a tracked file.

I think the author is just combining some things so he can show a clear example.

It would have been better if he had left out the line `Initialized empty Git repository in /home/john/simplegit/.git/`

Comment: "when you clone a repo, git doesn't say Initialized empty Git repository" => fixed upstream: https://github.com/progit/progit2/pull/414

Comment: @MatthieuMoy nice work, thanks, I was going to do it later but no need now :-)